# How to extract data from the file by using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file, in that emailid, phoneno and my dateofbirth is there. In python by using regular expression, how to find the 3 fields one by one? The desired output looks like

```
Emailid: x@gmail.com
Phoneno: 1234567890
dateofbirth: xx-xx-xx
```

I knew how to find the fields individually. But I am not aware how to find 3 at a time .The below snippet shows how to find the emailid from the file. This code output looks like

```
Emaildid: x@gmail.com
```

## ...........................

```
import sys,re

pattern=r'''(?P<emailid>[a-zA-Z\.]*\@[a-zA-Z]*\.c[a-zA-Z]*)'''


regobj = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)

for line in sys.stdin:
  results= regobj.finditer(line)
for result in results:
  sys.stdout.write("%s\n"%result.group('emailid'))
```

Comment: Are all three pieces of information always together, on the same line? In that case, you don't need to find them with one regular expression, you can just parse the line 3 times. If it's more complicated than that, then we need to see some examples of the file you're parsing.

Comment: Now the code looks much better than earlier...

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string using the `finditer` method as follows:

```
import sys,re

pattern = re.compile(r'''(?P<emailid>[a-zA-Z.]*@[a-zA-Z]*\.c[a-zA-Z]*).*?(?P<phone>\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}).*?(?P<dob>[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})''', re.DOTALL)

for result in pattern.finditer(sys.stdin.read()):
    sys.stdout.write("Emailid: %s\n"%result.group('emailid'))
    sys.stdout.write("Phoneno: %s\n"%result.group('phone'))
    sys.stdout.write("dateofbirth: %s\n"%result.group('dob'))
```

Comment: @subodh:  I am getting the below error while executing your code........                                                                                                                                                                                             for result in pattern.finditer(sys.stdin):
    TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: After the editing done by @martin-atkins, the code should work without any errors.